# How can I open files with my program on it's startup

Tags: file-association

I have a simple WAV player written in Python, but the only way to play files with it is to run the script and open the file through file dialog.

How could I make the script open the files like: right click to the file -> open with -> my script?

If you want the source code, comment it and I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This looks like what you want.](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) Just make sure your Python script can recieve the path to a file as a command line argument.

Also, you can try dropping the file on the main Python file, which will be as if you typed `python mypythonscript.py C:\path\to\my\file.txt` in a command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give your OS, so this answer is specific to Windows:

If you only want it to be accessible via right-click, you can do a registry edit.

however, then you'll need to code your script so it accepts console parameters (i.e., so you can type in a console `py myscript.py -filetoplay.wav -myargs`)

You can do this with the `sys` module (`sys.argv` can be evaluated to get a list of parameters, starting with the filename), but an in-depth answer on that doesn't belong here. ask on stackoverflow if you need help with that.

anyway, once you got that running, you can type `regedit` into the cmd. the registry will open and you can navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.wav\shell\Open with MyScript\command`(if it's not there, create it via New->Key and call them accordingly, the last being "command").

then you select "command" and right-click into the white field on the right. there you create a new value of the type `REG_SZ`. Select it, right-click->Change value, and then insert this as value: `"C:\PathToYourPython\pythonw.exe" "C:\Path\to\MyScript.pyw" "%1"`

Yes, with all the quotation marks.

the `"%1"` will be converted to `"path\of\filetoplay.wav"`

Hope that helps.